# reactjs - Function not working inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component to display list of **tags**, and the user can select tags to follow them. The tags are displaying fine. I would like to get the selected tag and store it inside a new array **tagsSelectedList**. So, when the user clicks a Tag, I would like to get that tag and push it to **tagsSelectedList**. However I am getting an error after I placed an `onClick` inside the `li` of the map function.

```
return (
    <li id={Tag.tagName} class="tag" key={Tag.id} onClick={this.selectTag}>{Tag.tagName}</li>
);
```

This is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectTag' of undefined

Component.js:

```
let tags = [
    {id: "1", tagName: "Arts"},
    ...
    ...
    {id: "59", tagName: "Writing"}
}];

var tagsSelectedList = [];

export default class SignUpSubscribeTags extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    selectTag = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.id);
    }

    render() {
        let tagList = tags.map(function(Tag){
            var i = 0;
            return (
                <li id={Tag.tagName} class="tag" key={Tag.id} onClick={this.selectTag}>{Tag.tagName}</li>
            );
        });

        return(
            <div id="signup-process-wrapper-addTags">

                <div id="add_tags">
                    <ul id="tag_list">
                        {tagList}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However if I remove `onClick={this.selectTag}` from the return statement of **tagList**,

```
<li id={Tag.tagName} class="tag" key={Tag.id}>{Tag.tagName}</li>
```

and place a `li` with an `onClick={this.selectTag}` inside the ul,

```
                <ul id="tag_list">
                    <li id="tagName" class="tag" onClick={this.selectTag}>tagName</li>
                    {tagList}
                </ul>
```

it works fine! I get no error.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to scope `this` so it references the React component context

**There are a couple of ways to do this:**

#### Option 1:

Using bind()

```
render() {
    let tagList = tags.map(function(Tag){
        var i = 0;
        return (
            <li id={Tag.tagName} class="tag" key={Tag.id} onClick={this.selectTag}>{Tag.tagName}</li>
        );
    }.bind(this));

    return(
        <div id="signup-process-wrapper-addTags">

            <div id="add_tags">
                <ul id="tag_list">
                    {tagList}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

#### Option 2:

You can use the ES6 arrow function to scope it

```
    let tagList = tags.map((Tag) => {
        var i = 0;
        return (
            <li id={Tag.tagName} class="tag" key={Tag.id} onClick={this.selectTag}>{Tag.tagName}</li>
        );
    });
```

#### Option 3:

The `map` function also takes a second argument that specifies what `this` refers to

```
    let tagList = tags.map(function(Tag) {
        var i = 0;
        return (
            <li id={Tag.tagName} class="tag" key={Tag.id} onClick={this.selectTag}>{Tag.tagName}</li>
        );
    }, this);
```

Comment: Yes. Working. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, `this` can be a confusing concept in javascript, I recommend you put aside the time to understand why the above is necessary and how lexical scoping works, it will save you from a lot of frustration in the future.