# reactjs- A custom function that passed as a prop into an component that inside of map function doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, class, this, react-class-based-component

I am doing a to-do app but with Class Components in React because I wanted to learn logic of state before Hooks.

I have only one index.js file so it's not that complicated.

These are my packages:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom/client");
```

This is my first root component:

```
class TodoComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos: ["wash up", "eat some cheese", "take a nap", "buy flowers"],
    };
  }

  onDelete(item) {
    var updatedTodos = this.state.todos.filter(function (val, index) {
      return item !== val;
    });

    this.setState({
      todos: updatedTodos,
    });
  }

  render() {
    var todos = this.state.todos;
    todos = todos.map(
      function (item, index) {
        return <TodoItem item={item} key={index} onDelete={this.onDelete} />;
      }.bind(this)
    );

    return (
      <div id="todo-list">
        <p>The busiest people have the most leisure...</p>
        <ul>{todos}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And This is my second component:

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleDelete() {
    this.props.onDelete(this.props.item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <div className="todo-item">
          <span className="item-name">{this.props.item}</span>
          <span className="item-delete" onClick={this.handleDelete}>
            {" "}
            x
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

And createRoot:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<TodoComponent />);
```

There wasn't any problem till I wanted to delete the items in the list. When I click the "x" that inside of span it shows me this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onDelete')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onDelete')
```

I was expecting to delete the item obviously.

I have checked this question:

[reactjs - Function not working inside a map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431787/reactjs-function-not-working-inside-a-map-function?rq=3)

but I had already did this in my code.

So I wrote

```
console.log(this.props.onDelete);
```

into the render method of `TodoItem` component to check wheter I did succeed or not to pass the `onDelete` method as a property and actually yes I am getting the code perfectly.

At this point I couldn't find any other solution. I am just guessing that this happens because my lack of knowlodge of `this` keyword's scope or something about using component inside of `map function`.

Because in here my problem looks kinda close to that link

[reactjs - Function not working inside a map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431787/reactjs-function-not-working-inside-a-map-function?rq=3)

and they solve it by just putting

```
.bind(this)
```

but it didn't work out on mine code so only difference between mine and his code is I am using a component inside the map function and he just use an `li` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind from both `TodoComponent` and `TodoItem`.
In `TodoComponent` bind the onDelete method

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos: ["wash up", "eat some cheese", "take a nap", "buy flowers"]
    };

    this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
  }
```

In `TodoItem` component bind the handleDelete method

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Bind the method in the constructor
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
  }
```

Check the codesandbox for full functional code

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-class-component-forked-4gk8l2?file=/src/TodoItem.js:71-210